# Slowing down Google Maps API AutoCompleteTextView suggestions

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using the Google Places API in my Android app and the suggestions are coming way too fast and chewing through my usage quota.

The code I used to get this running is: https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android

The resource alludes to a "timeout" of sorts but never readdresses it.

Is there a way to either:

A) Show suggestions when they stop typing for a moment?

-or-

B) Show suggestions every xx seconds?

Comment: I'm not sure why people are voting to close.  To me, the question seems specific and on-topic.

Comment: There is no reason at all to close it. This is a programming related question about an Android component.